# Join Two Linq Queries into a Single Selection without foreach loop

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a need to create a new model from two queries.  I have a **Member** entity and a **MemberTeam** entity, with both of them having references to each other.  What I need is a list of **all** members and to know if the member is assigned to a given team.

I currently have the following code which works but seems clunky to me, and I am hoping that someone has a better method to create this combined list using only Linq statements (without foreach).  Basically, the code gets a list of all members, gets another list of members that are assigned to a team and then uses a foreach loop to see if the the member is assigned to the team.

```
  int teamId = 1;
  var model = new SelectedMemberListModel();
  List<Member> allMembers = _unitOfWork.RepositoryFor<Member>().All().ToList();
  List<Member> teamMembers = _unitOfWork.RepositoryFor<MemberTeam>().AllIncluding(x => x.Members).Single(x => x.Id == teamId).Members.ToList();
  List<SelectedMemberModel> membersWithTeamSelected = new List<SelectedMemberModel>();
  foreach (var member in allMembers)
  {
    SelectedMemberModel selectedMemberModel = new SelectedMemberModel();
    selectedMemberModel.FirstName = member.FirstName;
    selectedMemberModel.LastName = member.LastName;
    if(teamMembers.Contains(member))
    {
      selectedMemberModel.Selected = true;
    }
    membersWithTeamSelected.Add(selectedMemberModel);
  }
```

If needed to understand my model better, here are my entities:

```
public class Member
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public int TeamId { get; set; }
  public virtual MemberTeam Team { get; set; }
  //... Other properties here...
}

public class MemberTeam
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }
}

public class SelectedMemberModel
{
  public int MemberId { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if I understood you correctly - but I think these might be the queries that you need?

This one will return a list of ...Model object only for selected members (those that are in teamMembers list):

```
var assignedOnly = allMembers
                     .Where(m => teamMembers.Contains(m))
                     .Select(m => new SelectedMemberModel() { 
                         FirstName = m.FirstName, LastName = m.LastName, 
                         Selected = true, MemberId = m.Id});
```

And this query should return all the members as ...Model objects, where the selected property is set based on the same condition as above:

```
    var allToModel = from m in allMembers
                     let selected = teamMembers.Contains(m)
                     select new SelectedMemberModel() { 
                       FirstName = m.FirstName, LastName = m.LastName, 
                       Selected = selected, MemberId = m.Id };
```

Anyway, I wouldn't expect this to be more efficient than the foreach loop.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I misunderstood the intent - I thought you wanted to get rid of the foreach so I ignored anything apart the loop, however it makes perfect sense to make just one db call.
I'm not too familiar with the entity framework, but I think the following linq statement will be enough - it operates only on the allMembers list using the teamId value to evaluate if the member is in the selected team.
Let me know if that solves your problem.

```
var selectedMemberModelList = allMembers
                                 .Select(m => new SelectedMemberModel() {
                                    FirstName = m.FirstName, LastName = m.LastName,
                                    MemberId = m.Id, Selected = m.Id == teamId})
                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Joanna, thank you for the feedback.  Your second method was what I was looking for.  I see your point about efficiency, though.  It looks cleaner, but it still requires two queries against the database (for allMembers and teamMembers).  I was hoping for a single selection statement, but your suggestion is still cleaner.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: @bmccleary - I've changed the query and it seems far simpler now. It seems also to be doing what you wanted - see update 2.